# Find the real and imaginary parts of $z^{22}=\sqrt{3} - i$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I know how to find the roots of this answer, but I believe this question is asking for something different as I don't believe I am expected to write out all 22 roots. I am not looking for the answer exactly, but I would like some help getting started on the right track as I don't know how to begin the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the polar form of a complex number?

Comment: Check the wording. Maybe it is saying that $z=\sqrt{3}-i$, and asks for the real and imaginary parts of $z^{22}$. Not so bad, only one calculation.

Comment: if you are familiar with complex number and its Euler representation, then you can use De-Moivre's theorem to do it easily. Look them up if you don't know these things.

Comment: I do know Eurler and I think I understand De-Moivre's, but I am not sure how to apply it. Do I simply raise the complex number in polar form to the power of 22?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\sqrt{3}-i = 2e^{-\frac\pi 6 i}$$

This is true by [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but I don't know what to do now.

Comment: @bah Have you tried taking the 22nd root?

Comment: Multiply it by 1/22? No, I haven't. What does that do?

Comment: No, not multiplying by 1/22. 22nd root: $$\sqrt[22]{z^{22}}=\sqrt[22]{2e^{-\frac\pi 6 i}}$$

Comment: Sorry, raising to the power of 1/22. But still, what does that do? The question asks for the real and imaginary parts, implying multiple answers, why would doing this get me more than one answer? And more importantly, how would one actually go about doing that.

Comment: So, bah, if you have $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $z^{1/n}=r^{1/n}e^{i\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ takes on all values from zero to $2\pi$ such that $n\alpha$ and $\theta$ differ by a multiple of $2\pi$.